# Verify whether one of  three methods is invoked with mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have three methods like these ones:

```
public void method1(String str){
    ...
}

public void method1(String str, String str2, String str3){
    ...
}

public void method1(String str, String str2, Object[] objs, String str3){
    ...
}
```

I want to check in Mockito if any of these methods are invoked, so I've tried to use anyVararg Matcher:

```
verify(foo).method1(anyVararg());
```

but this doesn't compile "The method method1(String, String) in the type Errors is not applicable for the arguments (Object)"

I have two questions:

1. How can I solve this?
2. Is there any way to check if any of two methods are invoked? Imagine I have another mathods called method2 and method3. I'd like to check if any of them is invoked (but at least one).

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You could do this by using an `Answer` to increment a counter if any of the methods are called.

```
private Answer incrementCounter = new Answer() {
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        counter++;
        return null;
    }        
};
```

Note that you need to stub all methods.  A method's uniqueness is based on its signature and not just the method name.  Two methods with the same name are still two different methods.

```
doAnswer(incrementCounter).when(mockObj.method1(anyString()));
doAnswer(incrementCounter).when(mockObj.method1(anyString(), anyString()));
doAnswer(incrementCounter).when(mockObj.method2(anyString()));
```

See documentation for `doAnswer` [here](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#12).

Comment: What is the doAswer method, is it part of Mockito ?

Comment: @AbdenaceurLichiheb Yes it's the static method `org.mockito.Mockito.doAnswer`

Answer (score 2):

A vararg method has a signature like this:

```
public void myMethod(String ... arguments){}
```

None of your methods is a vararg method.

I don't know Mockito so I can't solve your problem for you, but there is no possible abstraction over all three of the above methods unless you use reflection, so I guess you will have to use separate cases for each of the above methods.

Comment: oh OK thanks, I misunderstood the example at http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Matchers.html#anyVararg() Is there anything to check if any of these methods are invoked?

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept all calls on object like in this answer:
[Mockito - intercept any method invocation on a mock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839253/mockito-intercept-any-method-invocation-on-a-mock)
and then put combine this with approach suggested by @Bozho:

```
private Answer incrementCounter = new Answer() {
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        if (invocation.getMethod().getName().eqauls("someMethid")) {
            counter++;
        }
        return null;
    }        
};

VendorObject mockObj = mock(SomeClass.class, incrementCounter);
```

Note: if you provide other interceptor for any of this methods - default will not be invoked.