# Mockito - intercept any method invocation on a mock

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

Is it possible to intercept all method invocations on a mock in a generic way?

**Example**

Given a vendor provided class such as:

```
public class VendorObject {

    public int someIntMethod() {
        // ...
    }

    public String someStringMethod() {
        // ...
    }

}
```

I would like to create a mock that re-directs *all* method calls to another class where there are matching method signatures:

```
public class RedirectedToObject {

    public int someIntMethod() {
        // Accepts re-direct
    }

}
```

The when().thenAnswer() construct in Mockito seems to fit the bill but I cannot find a way to match any method call with any args.  The InvocationOnMock certainly gives me all these details anyway.  Is there a generic way to do this? Something that would look like this, where the when(vo.*) is replaced with appropriate code:

```
VendorObject vo = mock(VendorObject.class);
when(vo.anyMethod(anyArgs)).thenAnswer(
    new Answer() {
        @Override
        public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {

            // 1. Check if method exists on RedirectToObject.
            // 2a. If it does, call the method with the args and return the result.
            // 2b. If it does not, throw an exception to fail the unit test.

        }
    }
);
```

Adding wrappers around the vendor classes to make mocking easy is not an option because:

1. Too large an existing code base.
2. Part of extremely performance critical applications.

Comment: Don't tell me it's as simple as when(vo).thenAnswer(...) :O

Comment: "Part of extremely performance critical applications." How is adding a mock/proxy object any different than adding a wrapper in this case? Are you interested in doing this for just unit testing, or in the actual app?

Comment: @mattb: The performance aspect is not the greatest argument against using wrapper classes.  We'd create an interface based on the original vendor object and an implementation class that forwards requests to the actual vendor object.  The execution time for this is going to be small compared to the actual vendor object doing it's work.  The more important argument is the existing code base using the vendor objects directly.

Comment: Sounds like a job for Aspect Oriented Programming.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
VendorObject vo = mock(VendorObject.class, new Answer() {
    @Override
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {

        // 1. Check if method exists on RedirectToObject.
        // 2a. If it does, call the method with the args and return the
        // result.
        // 2b. If it does not, throw an exception to fail the unit test.

    }
});
```

Of course, if you want to use this approach frequently, no need for the Answer to be anonymous.

From the [documentation](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#mock%28java.lang.Class,%20org.mockito.stubbing.Answer%29): "It's quite advanced feature and typically you don't need it to write decent tests. However it can be helpful when working with legacy systems."  Sounds like you.

Comment: [`InvocationOnMock`](https://site.mockito.org/javadoc/current/org/mockito/invocation/InvocationOnMock.html)