# Mock object to run different void method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, powermock

I am trying to write testcases for a method I've implemented that in turn uses a third party cache provider.
The problem I am facing is that the cache is asyncronous, making it quite hard to test since the element put into cache are not instantly in the cache.

My solution to this was to just mock the cache using PowerMockito.
I can make it so that it always returns the same object, but preferable I want it to put the object into a `HashMap`on put and get it from the same map on a get operation.
The get operation should be pretty simple, something like:

```
    final Map<String, Object> cacheMap = new HashMap<>();
    Answer<Object> getFunction = invocation ->  
            cacheMap.get(invocation.getArgument(0));
    when(mockCache.get(any())).thenAnswer(getFunction);
```

But I am not sure how to mock a similar call for the void method `mockCache.put(any(), any())`
It atleast seems as if you cannot mock void functions to anything other than calling the real method or doing nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for intercepting the original call and rerouting it to a different implementation. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839253/mockito-intercept-any-method-invocation-on-a-mock) answer for an explanation how to do it.